# std::vector iterator type and permissible operations

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++17, contiguous

[C++ named requirements: ContiguousIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator) refers to the type of an iterator to `std::vector` as contiguous. But there is no definition provided for the type contiguous iterator [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags).

[std::vector::begin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) refers to the iterator type as random access iterator.

Does this imply that contiguous iterator is of type random access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPPReference is leading you astray by portraying an iterator category and concept `ContiguousIterator` that do not appear in the C++ Standard. C++17 defines contiguity as a property of iterators, much like mutability. [[iterator.requirements.general]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#6):

> Iterators that further satisfy the requirement that, for integral values `n` and dereferenceable iterator values `a` and `(a + n)`, `*(a + n)` is equivalent to `*(addressof(*a) + n)`, are called *contiguous iterators*.

Notably this property is independent of iterator category. In theory, you could define an iterator that satisfies the *contiguous iterator* requirements and the requirements of any of the iterator categories.

In practice, I don't think this flexibility provides any expressiveness over a design in which contiguous iterators are a refinement of random access iterators. In fact the standard library container requirements define *contiguous container* as ([[container.requirements]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#general-13)):

> A *contiguous container* is a container that supports random access iterators and whose member types `iterator` and `const_­iterator` are contiguous iterators.

which does not precisely contradict [iterator.requirements.general]/6's notion that contiguity is independent of iterator category, but it does introduce an inconsistency that helps to cause confusion.

Comment: We already made up the whole set of camel-cased iterator concepts (`RandomAccessIterator` and the like). I'm somewhat inclined to just make it up some more and say that `ContiguousIterator` refines RAIs.

Comment: @T.C. In fairness, I should admit that I *just* submitted a proposal to add support for contiguous iterators / ranges to the Ranges TS with almost exactly that design. I don't know what WG21 was thinking when they decided to make contiguity orthogonal to iterator category.

Answer (score 4):

> [a] contiguous iterator is of type random access?

Yes.

A "contiguous iterator" is defined (see [N3884](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3884.pdf)) as

> a random access iterator that also meets the following requirements:
>
> `std::pointer_from(i) == std::addressof(*i)` (when `i` is dereferenceable)
>
> `std::pointer_from(i + n) == std::pointer_from(i) + n` (when `i + n` is a valid iterator)

So

- "contiguous iterator" imply "random access iterator"
- "random access iterator" doesn't imply "contiguous iterator" (see `std::deque` for a counterexample)

Answer (score 2):

Yup. [cppreference has a nice chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator), that makes it clear that `ContiguousIterator` encompasses a superset of the features of `RandomAccessIterator` (which is itself a superset of `BidirectionalIterator`, which is a superset of `ForwardIterator`, etc.).